# SQL Joining with single dates when Multiple Dates occur but limited by a frequency count

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

In SQL I am looking to join two tables with multiple dates in one table linked to one date in another table which I want restricted by the frequency from one table. Instead I keep getting a total sum of all my records for all the frequencies.

I've tried joins, where clauses and subqueries but keep getting it wrong. I've recently been directed to Dibble and felt this was the best way to demo the problem:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9fec08a4ec5130c93da6ed663259da4

Example tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Action
(
ActionWeek date, 
ActionYear int,
Region nvarchar(50), 
Action nvarchar(50), 
ActionAmount int, 
Frequency int);

INSERT INTO Action values
('2019-01-01' , 2019, 'Wales', 'abc123', 123, 1),
('2019-03-10' , 2019, 'Wales', 'abc123', 132, 2),
('2019-06-01' , 2019, 'Wales', 'abc123', 153, 3),
('2020-01-11' , 2020, 'Wales', 'abc123', 123, 1),
('2019-01-01' , 2019, 'Australia', 'abd133', 723, 1),
('2019-08-01' , 2019, 'Australia', 'abd133', 763, 2),
('2020-04-01' , 2020, 'Australia', 'abd133', 823, 1),
('2019-01-01' , 2019, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3123, 1),
('2020-03-01' , 2020, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3223, 1),
('2020-05-01' , 2020, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3423, 2),
('2020-08-21' , 2020, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3623, 3),
('2021-01-01' , 2021, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3723, 1),
('2021-09-01' , 2021, 'Mexico', 'cbc423', 3823, 2)

-- Second Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Response
(
ResponseYear int,
ResponseAction nvarchar(50),
ResponseDate date, 
ResponseWeek date, 
ResponseValue float,
);


INSERT INTO Response values
(2019, 'abc123', '2019-02-04', '2019-02-01', 50),
(2019, 'abc123', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-08', 25),
(2019, 'abc123', '2019-09-24', '2019-09-24', 100),
(2020, 'abc123', '2020-01-20', '2019-01-23', 5),
(2021, 'abc123', '2021-06-10', '2021-06-07', 3),
(2019, 'abd133', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-07', 15),
(2019, 'abd133', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-04', 25),
(2019, 'abd133', '2019-03-10', '2019-03-04', 35),
(2021, 'cbc423', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-11', 77)
```

Desired results would be:

```
A.ActionWeek / A.Action / A.Frequency / R.ResponseValue
2019-01-01 / abc123 / 1 / 75
2019-03-10 / abc123 / 2 / 0
2019-06-01 / abc123 / 3 / 100
2020-01-11 / abc123 / 1 / 8
2019-01-01 / abd133 / 1 / 75
2019-08-01 / abd133 / 2 / 0
2020-04-01 / abd133 / 1 / 0
2019-01-01 / cbc423 / 1 / 0
2020-03-01 / cbc423 / 1 / 0
2020-05-01 / cbc423 / 2 / 0
2020-08-21 / cbc423 / 3 / 0
2021-01-01 / cbc423 / 1 / 77
2021-09-01 / cbc423 / 2 / 0
```

Let me know if you other questions?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT  A.ActionWeek, A.Action, A.Frequency
, (SELECT SUM(R.ResponseValue)
 FROM Response R2
 JOIN Action A2 ON R2.Action and A2.Action
 WHERE A.Frequency = A2.Frequency
) AS ResponseValue
FROM Action A
JOIN Response R ON A.Action = R.ResponseAction 
GROUP BY A.ActionWeek, A.Action, A.Frequency
ORDER BY A.ActionWeek, A.Action, A.Frequency
```

Comment: The fiddle is great, but a question here is supposed to be self-contained. I.e. add sample data and the expected result here, all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Fair point - Added in.

Comment: bring more clarity to your question

Comment: ' I want restricted by the frequency from one table.' - I have no idea what this means.

Comment: So... There is a Frequency number to demonstrate each occurrence in the table Action and each Response in the table Response should correspond to the that action according to the date. So if the ResponseWeek is after the ActionWeek but before the next ActionWeek it would link to that Frequency.

Comment: That didn't help try explaining how you get to 2019-01-01 / abc123 / 1 / 75 from your data in detail.

Comment: So the 75 is the sum of 50 and 25 (the first two rows from Response table where the ResponseWeek is after the ActionWeek but before the next ActionWeek). This is calculated from Table ActionWeek (Frequency 1) of 2019-01-01 and action of abc123 happening before the next ActionWeek (Frequency 2).

Comment: Another example would be the 2019-03-10 / abc123 / 2 / 0. This is 0 as all the ResponseWeek for abc123 occur outside of this date range marked with Frequency 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what frequency has to do with this and you don't appear to need it given that it's simple to get the next date to use as a join test

```
with cte as
(select a.actionweek fromweek,a.action,a.frequency,
        lead(a.actionweek) over (partition by a.action order by a.actionweek) toweek
from  [action] a)
select cte.fromweek,cte.toweek, cte.action,cte.frequency,r.responseweek,r.responsevalue
       --sum(r.responsevalue) 
from cte
left join response r on cte.action = r.ResponseAction and  ResponseWeek between cte.fromweek and cte.toweek;
```

Results in

```
fromweek   toweek     action                                             frequency   responseweek responsevalue
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------ ----------------------
2019-01-01 2019-03-10 abc123                                             1           2019-02-01   50
2019-01-01 2019-03-10 abc123                                             1           2019-02-08   25
2019-01-01 2019-03-10 abc123                                             1           2019-01-23   5
2019-03-10 2019-06-01 abc123                                             2           NULL         NULL
2019-06-01 2020-01-11 abc123                                             3           2019-09-24   100
2020-01-11 NULL       abc123                                             1           NULL         NULL
2019-01-01 2019-08-01 abd133                                             1           2019-01-07   15
2019-01-01 2019-08-01 abd133                                             1           2019-02-04   25
2019-01-01 2019-08-01 abd133                                             1           2019-03-04   35
2019-08-01 2020-04-01 abd133                                             2           NULL         NULL
2020-04-01 NULL       abd133                                             1           NULL         NULL
2019-01-01 2020-03-01 cbc423                                             1           NULL         NULL
2020-03-01 2020-05-01 cbc423                                             1           NULL         NULL
2020-05-01 2020-08-21 cbc423                                             2           NULL         NULL
2020-08-21 2021-01-01 cbc423                                             3           NULL         NULL
2021-01-01 2021-09-01 cbc423                                             1           2021-01-11   77
2021-09-01 NULL       cbc423                                             2           NULL         NULL

(17 row(s) affected)
```

Changing this to sum

```
with cte as
(select a.actionweek fromweek,a.action,a.frequency,
        lead(a.actionweek) over (partition by a.action order by a.actionweek) toweek
from  [action] a)
select cte.fromweek,cte.action,cte.frequency,
       sum(r.responsevalue) 
from cte
left join response r on cte.action = r.ResponseAction and  ResponseWeek between cte.fromweek and cte.toweek
group by cte.action,cte.fromweek,cte.frequency
order by cte.action,cte.fromweek,cte.frequency

fromweek   action                                             frequency   
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------
2019-01-01 abc123                                             1           80
2019-03-10 abc123                                             2           NULL
2019-06-01 abc123                                             3           100
2020-01-11 abc123                                             1           NULL
2019-01-01 abd133                                             1           75
2019-08-01 abd133                                             2           NULL
2020-04-01 abd133                                             1           NULL
2019-01-01 cbc423                                             1           NULL
2020-03-01 cbc423                                             1           NULL
2020-05-01 cbc423                                             2           NULL
2020-08-21 cbc423                                             3           NULL
2021-01-01 cbc423                                             1           77
2021-09-01 cbc423                                             2           NULL
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(13 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm not very familiar with CTE - so I'm still digesting how it works once applied. But it is doing what I needed! Thank you